# Windows 8 can not be installed on my laptop

Tags: windows-8, installation

Recently I formatted my laptop running Windows 8 and after that I can not install Windows 8. I deleted the whole partition but after that it is saying that new partition can not be created on this partition with an error 0xa52dbcf0. But Windows 7 can be installed in the same hard disk with no error.

Comment: run the windows memory diagnostic.  its not uncommon for an installation to fail when there is bad memory.  or DL an ISO http://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your laptop came with Windows 8 installation should be simple. You have Windows 7 already. This should of fixed the partitioning that was broken after formating. Try installing Windows 8 again. (make sure you get the proper one there is pro and OEM only OEM I've found is off pirate bay and it wasn't cracked. Due to the fact that the product key is embedded on the UEFI it should auto authenticate). When Windows installs on a system you can fully wipe the drive (from the installation disk it should give you this option) this should reset it. Another thing to note is how you're installing Windows 8, the recovery disk is for recovery not installation and they suck.